# PHP library for openID

Tags: php, openid

Which is the best PHP library for openID integration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For PHP, I find **[Zend Framework OpenID Component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html)** to be really good.

You can also see all available OpenID libraries at [**this link**](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries)

Comment: I don't believe that Zend can do openid against google...am i wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The [PHP OpenID library](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/) is good.

Comment: UPDATE: project is unmaintained since 2020. Their web domain with documentation is expired. They do not answer anymore to any issue. The project is dead, and doesn't seem to run correctly over PHP8 (the code is so old that still uses `var` for class properties. — It's a pity because I think it was the only certified OpenID library.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [JanRain's library](http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.2/), they say its used by 80% of all OpenID enabled users, (possibly, it was one of the earliest ones), but you can also use them for OpenID authentication as a service provider using their RPX service, or just get them to do all the work for you via their [myOpenID domain tool](https://www.myopenid.com/new_domain).

Comment: UPDATE: project is unmaintained since 2020. Their web domain with documentation is expired. They do not answer anymore to any issue. The project is dead, and doesn't seem to run correctly over PHP8 (the code is so old that still uses `var` for class properties. — It's a pity because I think it was the only certified OpenID library.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenID's list of libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries).

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries available in the market, just just have to test the best according to your need but if you are thinking for providing Identity as OPENID provider then their are only three libraries there only are PHPOPENID Library, Zend and NetMesh InfoGrid LID. Mostly people choose Zend as they Provide the other types of Framework and make easy to impliment.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR also has a nice [OpenId package](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenID).