# Handling Google OpenID

Tags: php, openid

I'm trying to implement Google OpenID for my website, but I'm struggling to figure out how to handle the OpenID response I get.

At the moment, when you click a login button, it takes you to the Google site, asks you to login there and when i click 'Sign In' it takes me back to my site and I get the followingi n the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/return.php?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0          
&openid.mode=id_res          
&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud          
&openid.response_nonce=2009-11-07T02%3A50%3A43Zv7QGuR9bs7yijw          
&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Freturn.php          
&openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUfDUg3KHwhcQlAgh4cjISdyflaGuGzWJEpNzR8TnufNIvKLBex4
&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle          
&openid.sig=FRIZWu78OrjWgb%2Fkiqq%2B63Zs8Pk%3D
&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawn34aUewQCm4U9DSwJFm4rVyyw9Zi6S_1k
&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawn34aUewQCm4U9DSwJFm4rVyyw9Zi6S_1k
```

Now i have absolutely no idea what to do with this.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the overflowing text

Answer (score 3):

Use the [php-openid](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/) library to make OpenID requests and verify the responses from your PHP based website. Rolling your own OpenID is very complicated, and includes complex things like cryptography (eg: Diffie Hellman Key exchange).

The [openid specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) is an interesting read if you'd like to understand how things work, even if implementing it all would be too tedious. Here are [some more developer resources](http://openid.net/developers/).

To help get you started: In OpenID terminology your website is called a 'relying party' or 'consumer'. Google in this case, would be the 'identity provider' (a service that authenticates users).

There are also specifics [using on Google's OpenID implementation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) online.

But again, I highly recommend using a library.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try and understand how the php-openid library works. I saw this class for login 'http://www.andrewpeace.com/googleopenid/GoogleOpenID.php.txt' and that's how I got the response i got.

Comment: +10 for using a library.  Implementing OpenID properly is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

See [PHP library for openID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388749/php-library-for-openid) for a list of PHP OpenID libraries. As `Andrew Amott` said, implementing it yourself is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google has made very easy handling of OPENID Requests and other things for implementations , just login in to https://code.google.com/apis/console known as developers console and create the project and you have to click on Identification Toolkit and provide the the information and just provide simple link on website and OPENID is implemented