# Any good OpenID php consumer libs?

Tags: php, openid

I need a php lib that can auth using OpenID against sites offering this service, like Google, Yahoo, Wordpress, etc...
Anyone used any lib that actuallly works? I've tryied a few but couldn't get any to auth against Google, Yahoo, or Wordpress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP library for openID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388749/php-library-for-openid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/) by [Mewp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367607/mewp). It comes with a [great example](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/example.php) and has no unusual dependencies (the only requirement you need to be aware of is that of the CURL PHP extension). It's entirely self-contained, it's only one file, and the code is very readable. There are [more tasty details](http://mewp.s4w.pl/post/17).

Answer (score 1):

[Zend.OpenID](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.introduction.html)

With Zend Framework, you can simply use the Zend_OpenID  component without having to use the MVC functionality or any configuration files that are not concerned with OpenID

Answer (score 1):

[phpOIDC](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc) implements both consumer and provider for OpenID connect.
OpenID connect is a new spec that was released in 2014 and is worth looking at.