# Zend OpenId and Google

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

Does the current Zend_OpenId ( Release 1.10.8 ) work with Google? I am working on a project that will only use OpenId ( and maybe OAuth ) as the login and would love to know before spending countless hours with the *dreaded* Zend Framework :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, currently it does not.

But there is a lot of similar articles about how to "patch" zend_oauth to be able to work with openid 2.0

Like this: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6905

It really works, i use such solution for about half of year without any troubles.

ps: due to it is a some kind of "dirty hack" - this solution does not provide ability of retrieving additional info, such as `name`, `email`, etc.

Comment: I only need to authenticate the user, so any other info is not needed. As long as it works it works. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Real quick, does it still work with other openid providers besides google and yahoo?

Comment: with ones who provide openid v1.0

Comment: im trying to create something much like SO login. would most of those at least work?

Comment: yes, it would work, since all providers use oauth 1.0, except of google and yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

No, Zend_OpenId doesn't work with Google without patching.

You should use instead janrain implementation (http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/). It supports the OpenID Google Apps discovery.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388749/php-library-for-openid for a list of other PHP OpenID libraries.