# Zend Framework open id extensions with google

Tags: zend-framework, openid

How to use openid extensions with google? I have something like this, I allready applied some patches which are basically the same as here: http://ak33m.com/?p=71

It does work without extensions?

```
$extensions = new Zend_OpenId_Extension_Sreg(array(
    'nickname' => false,
    'email' => true,
    'fullname' => false
    ),
    null,
    '1.1'
    );

if ($form->isValid($post)) {

$open_id_adapter = new App_Auth_Adapter_OpenId($post['openid_identifier'],null, null, null, $extensions);
$result = $auth->authenticate($open_id_adapter);

} else {                                

$open_id_adapter = new App_Auth_Adapter_OpenId(null, null, null, null, $extensions);
$result = $auth->authenticate($open_id_adapter);
}
if ($result->isValid()) {
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage(array(
    'message' => 'U bent ingelogd',
    'status' => 'success'
));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe having a look at an [example ZF 1.11 application](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.com/2011/02/example-of-openid-facebook-and-twitter.html) that uses OpenID (including google) for authentication will clarify how to make it work (source code is also available).