# OpenID for dummies?

Tags: php, openid

I'm thinking about adding an openid widget to a toolkit I'm developing.

An important part of that is keeping the UI as simple as possible - although there's lots of openid tools available they mostly rely on providing a text input box to enter a URL - however as demonstrated here on SO - there are a lot of openID providers which use a generic URL as the endpoint - so it's simply a matter of clicking on a button/image. I want to provide this service. Indeed, I want to provide the facility to restrict the providers to an approved list.

(I've got openIds from various providers - but do not have a clue what the URLs are - that doesn't prevent me [from using sites like this](http://lenni.info/blog/2009/12/whats-my-google-openid-url/) which provide clickable sign-ins!)

Unfortunately [Valdimir's openid](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3290-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-OpenID-single-sign-on.html) class, Janrains [PHP OpenID](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled) libs, [Dope OpenId](https://github.com/stevelove/Dope-OpenID), and [LightOpenId](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/commits/master) just provide the text box.

Is there a directory of openID provider URLs anywhere? With redistributable graphics?

I did find [IDselector.com](https://www.idselector.com/) (where you need an OpenId to access most of the site - but *they do not implement their widget on their own site!!!!*) but its not very clear what the licensing is.

Are there other/newer libs I should be aware of? [This S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388749/php-library-for-openid) is nearly 3 years old!

TIA

C.

Comment: I would start [here](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/) for a directory of OpenID providers, also, maybe start with a few well known providers and expand them in your app over time? I tend to do this when working with 3rd party services

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more selectors:

- http://code.google.com/p/openid-ps/
- http://code.google.com/p/open-selector/
- http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/
- http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/

My personal favorite is openid-realselector ([demo](http://openid-realselector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html)).

Comment: Nice answer Alix - lots to choose from here - but although jquery/mootools/etc make providing funky graphics very easy, I'm trying to make my toolkit agnostic as far as javascript frameworks are concerned - also having a UI which is independent of the backend stuff should make it easier to pick and mix the functionality I need! But this has been a great help in understanding what the front end needs to provide.

Comment: There's a useful (at least from my perspective) discussion regarding the differences between Google's Openid implementation and that used elsewhere at http://hueniverse.com/2009/07/users-vs-identity-providers-in-openid/ . The big obstacle now seems to be the hold ups at Microsoft and Paypal in implementing openid

Answer (score 1):

The [open-id-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) project provides a jQuery-based method of generating a simple form for selecting an Open ID providor.  It comes with several common OpenID providors and the appropriate icons.

See a non-functional demo [here](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html).

Note that this is only part of the solution; you must still implement OpenID authentication on  the server-side, as well, and configure open-id-selector to leverage it (by directing the form to the appropriate path).

Comment: The open-id-selector project does look nice, I think I will think about using it in the near future

Answer (score 0):

Integrate [WebFinger](http://code.google.com/p/webfinger/), so you just have to offer an email input field.